# How to prevent page scroll to top after i close modal Or on backdrop click?

Tags: angular, scroll, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

It is working fine on a current page, but when i go to another page and back to previous page. The page always scroll to top whenever the modal close.

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration

Comment: It point out that scrollPositionRestoration is not exist in type 'ExtraOptions'.